# What is the way of integrating $\dfrac{-e^x\sin x}{e^x+1}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Integrating $\dfrac{-e^x\sin x}{e^x+1}$. This is needed for me to solve an ODE. The issue is that I also need to figure out how to integrate $\dfrac{e^x\cos x}{e^x+1}$ so maybe this will give me a hint.

Any assistance will be appriciated!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is able to compute the [result, as is done here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eqm0f3qcr36)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$. Then you can make the expansion $\frac{1}{1+e^x} = 1 - e^x + e^{2x} - e^{3x} + ...$. Now the sum of exponentials can be integrated.

Comment: Just expanding this answer, we have:$$\int \frac{e^x\sin x}{e^x+1}\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n e^{-nx}(\cos x+n\sin x)}{1+n^2}= \text{Re}\left[\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(i,1;i+1;e^{-x}\right)\right].$$